# Output Copy of table row if row constains a string

Tags: jquery, string

I have a table full of data.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="production-name">
<a href="string1.html">Number 1</a>
</td>
<td class="production-name">
<a href="string2.html">Number 2</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And a couple of empty tables

```
<table id="production-name1-output">
</table>

<table id="production-name2-output">
</table>
```

I'm trying to write some jQuery to check the strings of all href's inside .production-name table cells.

If the string matches "string1", output this entire table row inside the empty #production-name-1-output table

If the string matches "string2", output this entire table row inside the empty #production-name-2-output table

So far all I've managed to do is check the href for a string:

```
$('.production-date a[href*="string1"]').each(function() {
alert('Contains string 1');
});
```

But looping through this to check for multiple strings and then outputting the entire parent row in to a seperate table is beyond me.

Any help appreciated. Hopefully I'll learn a thing or two!

Thanks in advance.

Jamie

Comment: so you want to check if your .product-name 's anchor tag container href with : string1.html then append it inside empty table ? else if string2 then append it inside empty table 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution below. Here is how is works: You need to loop through the cells to look for a match. If a match is found, find the closest `tr` and clone it. Then append it to the empty table (be sure to add the `<tbody>` tag in the table.

```
  //loop the a tags in the class
 $('.production-name a').each(function() {

    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if( link === 'string1.html') {

      alert('Contains string 1');
      //get the row to a var
      var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr").clone()
      //place the row in the new table

      $("#production-name1-output > tbody:last-child").append(thisRow)

     //end the loop since you found a match
    return false
   }


});
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f92yy111/1/)

Comment: That's excellent. Thank you very much, Cory. I truly appreciate you're help, as well as the explanation and commented code to help improve my own knowledge going forward.